# Netlogo how to add a legend?

Tags: netlogo

I started to use netlogo and I would like to add a legend to the model.

I didn't found any way to do it.

Is there some standard way to do it?

I thought about adding image to the interface but I didn't find any way to do it.
For example I want that user will know is the green particle means and what the read means

[image]

Comment: What kind of legend are you trying to add? To a plot?

Comment: @LukeC No the legend of the model

Comment: @LukeC I have added image

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [bitmap extension.](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/bitmap.html)
Here is a result example:

[image]

the code:

```
extensions [bitmap]
....
let legend bitmap:import "symbology.png"
bitmap:copy-to-drawing legend 40 275
```

"symbology.png" is the name of the graphics file, and 40 275 are the location coordinates. You will have to test several image sizes and coordinates until it suits your needs.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know a great way to do this, the closest I've ever been able to get is to use a combination of specific `plot` set-ups and `note` widgets. As an example, start out with a plot called "Legend" with this setup to start:

[image]

Now size it to look something like this:

[image]

Now make a procedure to 'draw' legend guides (some detail in comments):

```
to setup-legend-plot
  ; Choose correct plot
  set-current-plot "Legend"
  clear-plot

  ; Define starting y and color
  let starts [ [ 10 green ] [ 7 red ] [ 4 blue ] ]

  ; for each value in starts
  foreach starts [ start ->
    ; make a range of values starting at the initial
    ; y value from 'starts'
    let s first start
    let f s - 2.5 
    let ran ( range s f -0.01 )
    create-temporary-plot-pen "temp"
    set-plot-pen-color last start

    ; draw lines at each y value to make it
    ; look like a solid drawing
    foreach ran [ y ->
      plot-pen-up
      plotxy 1 y
      plot-pen-down
      plotxy 2 y
    ]   
  ]
end
```

Calling `setup-legend-plot` should now make your "Legend" plot look like

[image]

Now you can make some `note` widgets and layer them over the blank space in the plot:

[image]

[image]

Not exactly straightforward, but definitely the closest I've found.

**Edit:**

"Closest I've found *for building a legend within NetLogo.*" Javier's answer is a far better approach if you can swing it.

Comment: Woah... ! I'm not sure I entirely approve, but that's a very creative technique. I'm impressed.

Comment: @NicolasPayette That's completely fair, but I'll still take the compliment. Cheers!